# Integration of $x^3/(x^2+2)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the integral of the following formula:

$x^3/(x^2+2)^2$

Using integral by parts, I've gotten $f(x) = x^3$ , $f'(x) = 3x^2$ , $g'(x) = 1/(x^2 + 2)^2$, and $g(x)= \ln(x^2 + 2)$

After using the formula $f(x)g'(x)=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx$, I've gotten $x^3\ln(x^2+2)^2-\int 3x^2\ln(x^2+2)^2dx$

After finding the integral of $f'(x)g(x)$, I've gotten the result $\int x^3/(x^2+2)^2dx$.

This is where I'm confused. I felt as if I did everything right, but I just ended up getting the same integral I had when I first started this problem. I don't know if I'm putting too much detail in this post or not. I just wanted to show I put effort into solving this myself.

Comment: Check the derivative of $g(x).$ It is not what you have supposed.

Comment: Wouldn't the derivative of ln(x) be 1/x?

Comment: Yes, but the derivative of $\ln f(x)$ is $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.$ For example, the derivative of $\ln x^2$ is $\frac{2x}{x^2}=\frac{2}{x}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$  \int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+2)^2}dx=\int\frac{1}{2}x^2\cdot \frac{2x}{(x^2+2)^2}dx=[\frac{1}{2}x^2\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2+2}]+\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

1) Why are you integrating by parts? Let $u=x^2+2$.

2) If you really want to integrate by parts, let $u=x^2$ and $dv=\frac{x}{(x^2+2)^2}\,dx$.

Comment: I'm not that great at it, so I'm trying to get in practice. That, and the worksheet I'm working on requires me to do so.

Comment: The substitution I suggested in 1) is easier. But if you really want to integrate by parts, you will find using 2) that $du=2x\,dx$ and we can take $v=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: The way you approached things, you need to integrate $\frac{1}{x^2+2)^2}$, which is not a lot of fun. The result is not $\log(x^2+2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint; you can write this as $$\int \left (\frac{x}{x^2+2} -\frac{2x}{(x^2+2)^2} \right ) \mathrm{d}x$$ then let $u=x^2+2$ for both new integrals.